# Copy by reference

Tags: javascript

As per my knowledge, objects in JavaScript are copied by reference and not value. But the below code that I wrote is not working as expected. Maybe I don't know the proper behavior. Please provide insight and possible solution to avoid cases like this.

My code:

```
var a = {
    obj:{u:1,v:2,w:3},
    setobj:function(objj){
        this.obj = objj
    }
};

var b = a;
var m = b.obj
console.log(m);
```

It prints - `{u:1,v:2,w:3}`,

then-

```
var c = a;
c.setobj({x:4,y:5});
console.log(c.obj);  //prints {x:4,y:5}
console.log(a.obj); //prints {x:4,y:5}
console.log(b.obj); //prints {x:4,y:5}
```

but:

```
console.log(m); //prints {u:1,v:2,w:3}
```

I was expecting m to contain the reference of b.obj, where b contains reference of a. The latter is working but the former(m's reference) is not working. Please provide an insight over this and tell me what am I missing. Is it very silly assumption of mine or is there something that I don't know?

Comment: Yes, your assumption is wrong. m is a reference to the object that was stored at b.obj. You overwrote that reference later, but it will not magically let m point to a new object. Also, "copy by reference" doesn't really make much sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The object is not copied, but the *reference* to the object *is* copied. The references themselves are values.

So, when you write `m = b.obj`, `m` points *directly* to the object 1,2,3. `m` is not a reference to `b.obj`, but a reference to (incidentally) the same object as to which `b.obj` is a reference.
So `m` and `b.obj` are both (now unrelated) references to the same object 1,2,3.

Then, when you overwrite `b.obj`, that reference changes to the object 4,5, but `m` is still a reference to the original object.

Answer (score 2):

`{u:1,v:2,w:3}` is a standalone object and has its reference  address.
when you assign `obj:{u:1,v:2,w:3}` 
, `obj`  reference address is equal to 
 {u:1,v:2,w:3} address. 
when you do `c.setobj({x:4,y:5});` a new address will be assigned to `obj`.

your code is equal to:

```
var anotherObject= {u:1,v:2,w:3}
var a = {
obj:anotherObject,
setobj:function(objj){
    this.obj = objj
    }
};
```